# Laravel collection increment values and keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

Hello,

How do I `decrement` all keys from a collection and convert it to an array?

So let's say I've a collection that looks like this:

```
Collection {#410 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    1  => 1,
    2 => 6  
  ]
}
```

I need that to convert like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => 1,
  1 => 6
]
```

I know I can do:

```
$collection->toArray();
```

But than I get this:

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => 1
]
```

I already looked at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) but can't find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a new array from the collection by looping over the existing collection and assigning the key to be the same as the current key -1.

```
$newCollection = collect([]);
$collection->each(function($item, $key) use ($newCollection) {
    $newCollection->put($key-1, $item);
});


//$newCollection has decremented keys
```

Answer (score 0):

From the described desired output it looks like you can use native PHP function **array_values** which

> returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
array_values($collection->toArray())
```

Comment: thanks for helping. This is not exactly what I mean. Because now it indexes the array numerically. I only need to decrement every array key.